# ons-navigator in a sub page loaded by a ons-navigator

Tags: onsen-ui

Is it possible to have a ons-navigator defined in a page loaded by another ons-navigator ?

I'd like to organize my project in files where one file is a "logical function" with all the pages related to that function defined as templates. But if I define anything other than the ons-page it gives me

```
Error: You can not supply no "ons-page" element to "ons-navigator".
```

I'd like to have something like this:

index.html:

```
<ons-navigator var="mainNavigator" page="book"></ons-navigator>
```

book.html:

```
<ons-navigator var="bookNavigator" page="bookone"></ons-navigator>
<ons-template id="bookone">
    <ons-page>
        <h1>bookone</h1>
    </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. Currently your parent-child order is like this:

navigator(mainNavigator in index.html) -> navigator(bookNavigator in book.html) -> page(bookone)

However, you must supply an `<ons-page>` to your navigator "mainNavigator", but you are supplying right now another `<ons-navigator>`, "bookNavigator". That's why you get that error, so try to make that every navigator has an ons-page as a child. Hope it helps!

Comment: ok I see I can use mainNavigator from book.html. Now the problem is that when I ng-include a page in book.html it does not show up...     <div ng-include="views/book-header.html">xxx</div>